# iOS app gets slow after recording video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

My iOS app can record video by using AVCaptureSession and play video at the same time.

but the problem is that app gets much slower after completed this function.

I don't know why... My app is ARC mode and I tried my recorder class that contains AVCaptureSession to nil but the problem was not solved.

Please tell me the possible reasons make app slow after recording video.

Thank.

Comment: Do you tried use Instruments to check for memory leaks?

Answer (score 4):

It's very important where you are storing recorded files.**The large files should be saved in document directory instead of RAM**.So don't save your recorded file in improper places like NSUserDefault,which results slow performance and memory issue.

Comment: I saved video file into document bu using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL... sigh...

Comment: OK.Just check whether you saving the data to any objects like NSData and clear the data immediately after saving to document directory

Answer (score 0):

ARC doesn't mean you should not manage your memory. Make sure the used memory is deallocated after recording the video. Maybe there is some leak?

Comment: This tiny app doesn't work efficient way... By the way, I found out that this app works fine without recording video even though allocated memory is higher than memory usage after recording video.